# Cabal compilation conditional on compiling with llvm or not

Tags: haskell, llvm, cabal, conditional-compilation

In a library I'm writing I need to use `CPP` to choose between two blocks of code depending on whether my user is compiling with LLVM or the native code gen. Is there a way to detect this in the `.cabal` file and do something like

```
library
  -- not real:
  if backend(llvm)
      CPP-Options:     -DUSING_LLVM
```

Or maybe it's even possible to detect arbitrary flags passed to GHC (instead of just `-fllvm`)?

Comment: How is the user choosing the compilation method? Usually that is done with a cabal flag.

Comment: @crockeea oh, hm. You mean as the library author I would make a new flag `usellvm` and I'd conditionally set `ghc-options: -fllvm`? I think on the few occasions where I've wanted to try compiling all my dependencies with llvm I've done `cabal install --only-dependencies --ghc-options=-fllvm`, but maybe that didn't really do the trick. In any case I'd like this to work regardless of how the user chose the compilation method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I forgot to check the GHC docs. GHC defines a macro `__GLASGOW_HASKELL_LLVM__` which is defined when `-fllvm` was specified (and can be used to check llvm version as well):

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-affecting-the-c-pre-processor